# Aligning RGB and depth images from D435i using pyrealsense2 and Orange Pi

Tags: python, computer-vision, stereo-3d, depth-buffer, realsense

I am facing an issue while trying to align RGB and depth images from a D435i camera using pyrealsense2 on an Orange Pi (similar to Raspberry Pi). The operation of aligning frames is taking a lot of time, resulting in a transfer rate of only 2.5 images per second.

To overcome this issue, I tried to serialize the composite_frame object using pickle.dumps() and send it over TCP. However, I got the following error "TypeError: cannot pickle 'pyrealsense2.pyrealsense2.composite_frame' object". I would appreciate any suggestions on how I can serialize this object so that I can send it over TCP.

I also attempted to align the frames manually by first extracting the depth and color frames and aligning them using the camera's internal and external reference, but I found that the depth map after coordinate mapping and RGB cannot be aligned. I have attached my code and the result of my attempt below. Can someone please point out my mistake or help me with aligning the images correctly?

Thank you all in advance for your help.

Dear community,

I am facing an issue while trying to align RGB and depth images from a D435i camera using pyrealsense2 on an Orange Pi (similar to Raspberry Pi). The operation of aligning frames is taking a lot of time, resulting in a transfer rate of only 2.5 images per second.

```py
frames         = pipeline.wait_for_frames()                   # Get Frame from D435i
aligned_frames = align.process(frames)      # Almost cost 400 ms on OrangePi, 80 times longer than other process
```

To overcome this issue, I tried to serialize the composite_frame object using pickle.dumps() and send it over TCP. However, I got the following error "TypeError: cannot pickle 'pyrealsense2.pyrealsense2.composite_frame' object". I would appreciate any suggestions on how I can serialize this object so that I can send it over TCP.

```bash
frames_serial = pickle.dumps(frames) gives the following error
TypeError: cannot pickle 'pyrealsense2.pyrealsense2.composite_frame' object
```

---

I also attempted to align the frames manually by first extracting the depth and color frames and aligning them using the camera's internal and external reference, but I found that the depth map after coordinate mapping and RGB cannot be aligned. I have attached my code and the result of my attempt below. Can someone please point out my mistake or help me with aligning the images correctly?

Thank you all in advance for your help.

```py
def pixel_to_pixel(u1, v1, K1, R1, t1, R1to2, t1to2, K2):
    # Convert pixel coordinates to coordinates in the normalized camera coordinate system
    x1 = (u1 - K1[0,2]) / K1[0,0]
    y1 = (v1 - K1[1,2]) / K1[1,1]
    z1 = 1

    # Convert the coordinates in the normalized camera coordinate system to the coordinates in the camera 1 coordinate system
    X1 = np.array([x1, y1, z1])
    X1 = X1 / np.linalg.norm(X1)

    # Convert the coordinates in the camera 1 coordinate system to the world coordinate system
    X = R1.dot(X1) + t1

    #  Convert the coordinates in the world coordinate system to the coordinates in the camera 2 coordinate system
    X2 = R1to2.dot(X) + t1to2

    # Convert the coordinates in the camera 2 coordinate system to the coordinates in the normalized camera coordinate system
    x2, y2, z2 = X2[0], X2[1], X2[2]
    x2 /= z2
    y2 /= z2

    # Convert coordinates under normalized camera coordinate system to pixel coordinates
    u2 = K2[0,0] * x2 + K2[0,2]
    v2 = K2[1,1] * y2 + K2[1,2]

    return int(u2), int(v2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    color_image = cv2.imread("RGB_1.png")
    depth_image = np.load("2.npy")

    K_1 = np.eye(3)
    R_1 = np.eye(3)
    t_1 = np.array([0, 0, 0])
    u_1, v_1 = 470, 470
    x_1, y_1 = pixel_to_pixel(u_1, v_1,
                              color_intrinsics,
                              R_1, t_1,
                              color_to_depth_rotation,
                              color_to_depth_translation,
                              depth_intrinsics)

    depth_temp = np.zeros_like(depth_image, dtype=np.float32)
    for i in range(color_image.shape[0]):
        for j in range(color_image.shape[1]):

            x, y = pixel_to_pixel(i, j,
                                  color_intrinsics,
                                  R_1, t_1,
                                  color_to_depth_rotation,
                                  color_to_depth_translation,
                                  depth_intrinsics)
            depth_temp[i][j] = depth_image[x][y] / 1000.0

            print(depth_image[x][y])

    cv2.imshow("test", depth_temp)
    color_image[depth_temp == 0.0] = (0, 0, 255)
    cv2.imshow("test_2", color_image)
    cv2.waitKey()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

(https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/82874862/235767167-81c690c3-3c4f-47ce-8ea4-a64524e8000b.png)
The Intrinsic parameters of RGB camera, depth camera and Extrinsic parameters from RGB to depth camera are all obtained by `rs-sensor-control` and written to the program manually.

```py
# Intrinsic parameters of depth camera
depth_intrinsics = np.array([[387.873657226562, 0.0,              323.414398193359],
                             [0.0,              387.873657226562, 238.799575805664],
                             [0.0,              0.0,              1.0]])

# Intrinsic parameters of color camera
color_intrinsics = np.array([[604.584350585938, 0.0,              309.198364257812],
                             [0.0,              604.356323242188, 254.28271484375],
                             [0.0,              0.0,              1.0]])

# Extrinsic parameters from depth to color camera
depth_to_color_rotation = np.array([[ 0.999885,   0.00396869, 0.0146583],
                                    [-0.00393271, 0.999989,  -0.0024827],
                                    [-0.014668,   0.00242477, 0.999889]])

depth_to_color_translation = np.array([0.0148551082238555,
                                       3.56109194399323e-05,
                                       0.000355124968336895])

# Extrinsic parameters from color to depth camera
color_to_depth_rotation = np.array([[0.999885,  -0.00393271, -0.014668],
                                    [0.00396869, 0.999989,    0.00242477],
                                    [0.0146583, -0.0024827,   0.999889]])

color_to_depth_translation = np.array([-0.0649821, -9.5427e-05, -0.000572748])
```